# Set one particular viewcontroller to landscape mode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, landscape

How we can set one particular viewcontroller to landscape mode in swift using xib?

```
func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        let orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask =
        [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
        return orientation
}
```

I am using the above code but it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can't be that specific for each view controller by using the storyboard.  If you are doing it in code as you are, you need to specify the override keyword for that function.  You also need to make sure that your app project supports all the interface orientations that you want to support for any particular view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the device orientation in your proyect target
[image: devide orientation]

and then in all viewControllers in portrait add

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown ||
        UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Unknown) {
            return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

finally in landscape viweController you want add

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown]
}
```